# Combo Box selected value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I send some data to the combo box using the view bag from the controller to the view.

In the view, there is a javascript when the combo box value is changed, I send that value to the controller again using an ajax call and get the related data, and show it in another textbox.

```
ViewBag.Task_Assigned_Branch_Id = new SelectList(db.Branch.Where(x=>x.Status ==true), "Id", "BranchName");
```

View

```
<div class="form-group row">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Task_Assigned_Branch_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      @Html.DropDownList("Task_Assigned_Branch_Id", null, "Select the Branch", new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown js-Branch", @Id = "Branch" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_Assigned_Branch_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $('.js-Branch').change(function () {
            GetBranchMembers($(this).val())
  });
```

This worked perfectly.

Then I want to change it, when sending the data to the view bag, I wanted to select a default value to the combo box and send it to the view.

So I changed the controller code to

```
ViewBag.Task_Assigned_Branch_Id = new SelectList(db.Branch.Where(x=>x.Status ==true), "Id", "BranchName", branchId);
```

Now the value is loading as the default selected value in the combo box.

So to get the combo box value in the loading event I wrote this

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        
        var e = document.getElementById("js-Branch");
        alert(e);
        GetBranchMembers(e)

    })
```

But the `id` returns null.

I guess because I sent the default value to the combo box, it doesn't pass the id to the script or something. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: js-Branch is a class not Id, so you need to  use correct Id i think 'Branch' is correct Id to use so use getElementById("Branch")

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code. i think you are using wrong id. you are using a class name in getElementbyId function

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        
        var e = document.getElementById("Branch");
        alert(e);
        GetBranchMembers(e)

    });
```